# "SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression" using template

Tags: python

To a function I am passing in a string `command` and a list of strings `ports`
     An example:

```
command = "a b c {iface} d e f"
ports = ["abc", "adsd", "12", "13"]
```

These get passed to this function where I want to get multiple strings for command, replacing
`{iface}` with each element in `ports`

```
def substitute_interface(command, ports):
    t = string.Template(command)
    for i in ports:
        print t.substitute({iface}=i)
```

I get the error in the title, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two errors:

1. As the error message says, keyword arguments must be identifiers, whereas `{iface}` is a expression (specifically, a set containing the current value of `iface`). The braces around the `iface` name are markup to tell the substitution engine *that* there is something to be substituted there. To pass the value for that placeholder, just supply the key `iface`, ideally by writing`t.substitute(iface=i)`.
2. `string.Template` doesn't support that syntax, it wants `$iface` (or `${iface}` if the former can't be used, but this case you can just use `$iface`). `str.format` supports this syntax, but apparently you don't want to use that.

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings):

> $identifier names a substitution placeholder matching a mapping key of
>   "identifier"

So you need a `$` sign otherwise the template will not be able to find the place-holder, and then pass `iface = p` to the `substitute` function or a dictionary.

```
>>> command = "a b c ${iface} d e f"  #note the `$`
>>> t = Template(command)
>>> for p in ports:
    print t.substitute(iface = p) # now use `iface= p` not `{iface}`
...     
a b c abc d e f
a b c adsd d e f
a b c 12 d e f
a b c 13 d e f
```

Without any modifications you can use this string `"a b c {iface} d e f"` with `str.format`:

```
for p in ports:
    print command.format(iface = p)
...     
a b c abc d e f
a b c adsd d e f
a b c 12 d e f
a b c 13 d e f
```

Comment: Well, he can, but this has nothing to do with the error in question. -1

Comment: Thanks for the possible way of doing it, I am more looking into template and wondering where I am in err :)